# Using MOD in Excel 2010 Data Validation acts differently from formulas

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-formula

Excel 2010

This formula displays True when given any 0.25 increment:

```
=MOD(A1,0.25)=0
```

However, when I use the formula (without the leading "=") in Data Validation, it always returns False. 
I've tried using Floor and Round, but without success. I've also tried using a completely new sheet and only bringing the formulae across in case there was some sort of formatting issue. I would have expected this to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried it WITH the leading =  ?  Works for me

Comment: Yes, adding a leading "=" makes the validation not trigger at all.

Comment: Well now I feel stupid... It's started working when using a leading =, and because I was referencing A1 instead of the top left cell of the range I should have been looking at. The combination of those 2 errors was the issue.

Comment: @Virtuoso Add self-answer with your solution to make the thread solved, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's started working when using a leading =, and because I was referencing A1 instead of the top left cell of the range I should have been looking at. The combination of those 2 errors was the issue.